# Concurrency Visualizer for UWP apps

Tags: concurrency, uwp

Is it possible to use the concurrency visualizer when developing for the UWP?
I've installed the plugin but i can't seem to get it working.

Comment: What plugin have you added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. Just use the Attach to process.. option to connect to a running UWP app.